# Change the background of the buttons "+", "-", "/", "*" when the button is pressed (clear and equal). (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, calculator

How can I make it so that when I press the button (clear and equal), the background "+", "-", "/", "*" changes to gray, as it was before pressing.

[image]

```
 @IBAction func AnAnimate(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.currentBackgroundImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_off") {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Image_on"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_off"), for: .normal)
    }
    if (previousButton !== sender) {
        previousButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_off"), for: .normal)

        previousButton = sender
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `outlet` of `button` so then when pressed the `button` then change the `background` color of all your `button` like that.

```
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
```